# Is it possible, to compile an exe to javascript?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, decompiler, emscripten

There are some C decompilers, and using emscripten and LLVM it is possible to build a C/C++ code to the web.

So is it possible somehow, to decompile the exe, and compile it to HTML and JS?

Comment: In a single word: No. How would the HTML look like? How would you convert arbitrary GUI code to HTML? How about non-gui programs?

Comment: In a single word: Yes.  But don't waste your time looking for off-the-shelf solutions.  It's up to you whether you spend your time developing a solution, but this is a hard problem.

Comment: It isn't possible to compile an exe to anything. It's already compiled. And linked. Do you perchance mean 'compile javascript to .exe'? Or *de*-compile an exe? To HTML and JS? Or what?

Comment: There is a number of decompilers from native to LLVM, all are far from  completeness. Your best bet would be to use an emulator like this one: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (usually) not possible.

The part of taking the `.exe`, decompiling it, then recompiling it into JavaScript alone is technically possible once someone writes such a tool.

The problem however is that most compiled applications link to a mess of libraries, which are required for them to run. In browsers JavaScript is running in an isolated environment, providing a very different interface to that provided when running a binary on your operating system. It is much like if you wanted to run that `.exe` (a Windows application) on Linux. While it is possible (Wine), it is not something straightforward, and for that matter, nobody would like to wait for a package that large like Wine to download before your decompiled application embedded into a web page would start.

Emscripten and the likes compile C into JavaScript knowing the differences of interfaces, much like you can create C code (with the help of cross-platform libraries such as SDL for example) which compiles for both Linux and Windows without changes. But the binaries still are not interchangeable: the decompiled `.exe` of this cross platform program would still be a Windows application.

Comment: Using emulators such as [Virtual x86](https://copy.sh/v86/), it is possible to run `.exe` files (or entire operating systems) in JavaScript.